# Saving an image in a LocalDB database and then displaying in main Index view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a create view that allows users to enter some basic information. I need to be able to let them upload an image. This is the code that is generated when I add the controller to the project for it:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

I don't know what code to put in this segment to give me the "choose a file" control. I know there has to be something out there pre-made but for the life of me I can't find it. On a related note: what should I define the type of the image to be in the model I created for it? After looking around, I saw that people were suggesting `byte[]` but I don't know how to display that in my index view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need `<input type="file" ... />` to select a file (and it posts back to a property which is `HttpPostedFileBase`)

Comment: Ok, that gives me the "choose file" and the button that goes with it but how do I actually go about saving the image when the "create" button is clicked? and also how do I go about showing it in the main index view?

Comment: You need to do some basic research. There are thousands of examples on the web of how to do this.